# Redirecting to correct view after login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

I'm trying to implement login functionality for a webapp. There's a Javascript version using JQuery and there's a non-Javascript version. The Javascript version is working fine, but I have a problem with the non-JS version:

Currently when the user clicks "login" I'm reloading the same page with a parameter which causes a loginform to be displayed (that means I don't have an explicit login view).

After the login or in case of any input errors I want the ViewController to go back to the view where the user initiated the login process. I cannot use a redirect for that, because especially the rejectedValues would be lost then. What I really need to do is redirect to the view-name on which the login-form was opened.

Is there a elegant way to do this or is it just a better idea to use a seperate login template?

Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 0):

It's not explicitely necessary redirect with spring (I guess you are using `RedirectView` or `"redirect://"`), you simply have to pass the parameter to the same view (with `ModelAndView` or whatever you use), indicating if you should show the login form or not.

If you used the classical `#springFormInput` , and used `#springShowErrors` tags accordingly, the error and the values will be recovered in the view, showing inside the login form because you have passed the variable to accomplish this in the controller.

Hope it helps.